# ZEND_Auth, deactivate navigation area

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-layout

I´ve built a Login Page using Zend_Auth. Now my question ist how can I deactivate areas which are loaded with my layout.phtml?

Here the part of my code of my layout.phtml which I don´t want to see in my login and logout forms:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'arbeitskalender', 'action'=>'index'), null, false);?>">Arbeitskalender</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'pdf', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Arbeitskalender download</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'bibliothek', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Bibliothek</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'schwestern', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Schwestern</a></li> -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I work with different layouts? In which place and how can I load them?

Comment: I would highly recommend using the [`Zend\Navigation`](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial.navigation.html#setting-up-zend-navigation) component to create your navigation. It would solve your problem as it integrates with the `Zend\Acl` (restricts the menu options based on you access level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple layouts in an application. If you create another without the navigation HTML and configure it in your `module.config.php`, you can simply select which layout to use from within the controller.

```
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'layout/layout_login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout_login.phtml'
)
```

Then in your controller:

```
$this->layout('layout/layout_login');
```

EDIT:

Alternatively if you'd like to dynamically change your layout you can use the [Identity View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.identity.html) to check whether a user is logged in or not. e.g.

```
<!-- if logged in, show logout link -->
<?php if (null !== $this->identity()) : ?>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```